# Polish-Born Canadian entering Poland

Tags: dual-nationality, poland, denial-of-entry

My wife is a Polish-born Canadian citizen.  She has not carried a Polish passport in over 20 years, nor has she done anything to maintain her Polish citizenship paperwork-wise.

Recently, the Polish government has stated that all Polish citizens must enter Poland on a Polish passport.  Since her Canadian passport lists her city of birth, she could be refused entry if she doesn't carry a Polish passport.

We are travelling to Poland in a few months for a family reunion.  Our flight is Toronto - Munich - Warsaw.  Our planned stay is 5 days.

From my understanding, since we are entering Schengen Europe in Munich, she will never have her credentials checked in Poland, and she will be fine travelling on her Canadian passport.

Is this thinking correct? Or should we go through the tedious process of getting her a Polish passport?

What's the worst that can happen?

Comment: You can get a Canadian passport that doesn't state your city of birth.

Comment: I'm not having the time to write a full answer, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship) and [Canadian travel advice](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/poland) are good starters. Unless your wife renounced Polish citizenship and this was accepted by the Polish government she is still a Polish citizen and thus must adhere to the laws, and one of them is to not *identifying oneself to Polish authorities using a foreign identification document*. In practice she might be fine as you are flying via MUC, can't tell. Get her a Polish PP while there?

Comment: There's a consulate in Toronto. We could get her one here, but it just seems to be tedious busywork.

Comment: @mts Arguably she'd be misrepresenting herself in Munich as well, since as a Polish citizen she's allowed to stay as long as she wants under DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC, rather than whatever the limit for Canadian citizens is.

Comment: @Robus I don't see why, there's German officers in MUC and AFAIK by German law it is not a crime to use any legit passport one owns to enter Germany, even if one is also a EU/Schengen citizen. Then on the flight to WAW there's no passport control, so again she would not be misrepresenting herself to an official. The intended duration of stay here seems to be well below the 90 days limit for Canadians.

Comment: I don't know if it's absolutely the worst that can happen, and it's not likely, but it is possible that the German immigration officials decide she's not admissible to the Schengen area and refuse entry, failing to recognize her claim to Polish citizenship, and she gets sent back to Canada.  If she has a Polish passport, this cannot happen.  Also, if she has a Polish passport, you can go with her to the EU passport line if you have your marriage certificate with you.

Comment: She wouldn't be representing herself as Polish, but as Canadian.

Comment: First of all, what's the worst that could happen? Foreigners attack and blow the entire nation up and we all die. I'm joking, of course, but the point is, you never know what exactly *could* happen, just what could *reasonably* happen. But seriously, and to the point, I would just make a reapplication for the passport, requesting an [omission of place of birth](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/passport/apply/omit-place-birth.asp). (Link to official Canadian passport office)

Comment: "She wouldn't be representing herself as Polish, but as Canadian": and there are far more grounds for refusing entry to Canadians than there are for refusing entry to EU citizens.  For example, Canadians coming for a short visit can be refused entry on suspicion of wanting to immigrate illegally, or to work without authorization, or even just to stay longer than 90 days.  Poles cannot be denied entry on those grounds.  So you asked for worst-case scenarios, and among those scenarios are those in which she is denied entry for a reason like that.

Comment: I wrote about her claim to Polish citizenship on the assumption that if the German authorities decided to send her home, she would raise that claim as a last-ditch effort to get past passport control.  In fact, if she were able to convince them that she is in fact Polish (possible, for example, if they find a record of her more-than-20-year-old Polish passport), they would have to admit her.

Comment: Caveat: place of birth in Canadian passport is no proof of having had Polish citizenship in the past (consider ambassadors 'children, or childbirth abroad in an emergency).

Comment: On private visits (not hotels) you are required to register after 4 days. At a Hotel registration will be done on arrival. As a Polish citizen she must show her Polish passport. Under International law, host countries are not required to recongnize another citizenship of it own citizens. The idea of many, that there are no **internal** controls within the Schengen Area is **very naive**, any policeman can execute such a control when they deem it fit.

Answer (score 6):

### Take a shot, or have her passport issued before you leave

edit:

### TLDR

The situation for Polish citizens who arrive in Poland while having a passport (and citizenship) of a third country (and not the Polish one) may be sometimes complicated. if the authorities required them to identify themselves and they are aware that this person is a Polish citizen, they are obliged by law to require Polish identification from them. There has been an issue where Polish-Canadian parents were travelling back to Canada with their 7-month old child and the child was denied to leave Poland, because it hasn't got a Polish passport (only the Canadian one). There was no problem on arrival, the issue was only on departure. The OP has prepared himself and his wife for that by travelling to Germany and then, to Poland. This might help. However, if you plan more frequent visits, it may reduce potential problems by having the passport issued.

**Worst case scenario:** Your wife will be denied boarding a plane in Poland during the border check, if one occurs in Poland, and not in Germany. This may happen when the flight to Canada will be in the same plane, and it will have just a mid-stop in Germany (Munich) for other passengers flying to Canada. If these flights are separate, you shouldn't have any problem, as the first one is in-Schengen flight. Please note that the border control officer **would have to gain a suspicion** that your wife is Polish and she is trying to leave Poland without proper travel document. It may sound unlikely (and I think it's unlikely), but you ask for the worst-case scenario. In that case, you should book a flight from Germany and travel from there.

**Best case scenario:** nobody would find out that your wife is Polish, except for her family (who already know that ;) ). You will travel as Canadian citizens according to general rules for Canadians travelling in the Schengen zone.

Source: [Polish Consulate in Vancouver](http://www.msz.gov.pl/pl/p/vancouver_ca_k_pl/c/MOBILE/aktualnosci/podwojneobywatelstwo)

1. Your wife is a Polish citizen. Therfore, she cannot be denied entry to Poland, as Article 52.4 of the Polish Constitution states:

> Obywatela polskiego nie można wydalić z kraju ani zakazać mu powrotu do kraju.
>
> Polish citizen cannot be expelled from the country or be denied return to the country.

However, if she hasn't any document to prove that, it will take some time to verify that. You probably do not need that.

2. You plan to enter Schengen zone in Germany. This is a smart move if you want to try using her Canadian passport. I cannot find any regulation which forces a EU-citizen to enter EU/Schengen zone using EU-issued passport. Please note that there is no guarantee that she (or you) will be granted entry to Germany (and therefore Schengen zone).
3. You plan to travel from Germany to Poland and stay in Poland while legally admitted in the Schengen zone. Unless a situation occurs when she will be forced to present her identification to Polish authorities, there should not be any problem. However, please note that according to Polish Citizenship Act of 2009:

> Art. 3.
>
> 1. Obywatel polski posiadający równocześnie obywatelstwo innego państwa ma wobec Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej takie same prawa i
>      obowiązki jak osoba posiadająca wyłącznie obywatelstwo polskie.
> 2. Obywatel polski nie może wobec władz Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej powoływać się ze skutkiem prawnym na posiadane równocześnie
>      obywatelstwo innego państwa i na wynikające z niego prawa i obowiązki.
>
> Art. 3
>
> 1. Polish citizen holding a citizenship of another country has the same rights and duties to the Republic of Poland as the person holding
>      Polish citizenship only.
> 2. Polish citizen cannot invoke with legal effect his/her citizenship of another country and any rights or duties resulting from that
>      citizenship against the authorities of the Republic of Poland.

Although both Germany and Poland are in the Schengen zone, there is a small chance that the border patrol may stop you when you are near the border (on both sides). Showing your Canadian passport with legal entry stamp to Schengen zone will suit you in Germany, and most likely in Poland too, however in the latter case that will not be legal. It is a violation of the law to use a foreign-issued identity document, if you are a Polish citizen.

I do not encourage you to travel without Polish passport or ID card (the latter can be issued in Poland only), but please remember during your stay, that there is no law requiring a Polish citizen to hold an ID document with himself/herself.

If you plan to fly to Munich, please note that you should also leave from outside of Poland. If your flight from Warsaw to Munich to Toronto is a combined flight, your wife may be denied exit from Poland as she will be a Polish citizen without valid travel document. These situations have happened before. If these flights are separate, you might get lucky.

### Summary

If you want to keep your trip simple, smooth and you enjoy avoiding problems, get a passport :) You still have few months to go, that should be more than enough to have it issued.

Comment: "It is a violation of the law to use a foreign-issued identity document, if you are a Polish citizen." - but what is the punishment for it? If none exists OP can just ignore it.

Comment: "You still have few months to go, that should be more than enough to have it issued." - possibly not, depending on what proof of former citizenship she has.

Comment: `If none exists OP can just ignore it.` - I thought that you do not suggest illegal actions on this site ;)

Comment: If you're unwilling to do the time, don't do the crime. As a corollary, if you're willing to do the time, do the crime. If no punishment exists it's not really illegal.

Comment: If she comes for 5 days, she does not want to spend any part of any day explaining herself to any Polish authority, even if there is no punishment - but that's my guess only :)

Comment: Are Polish citizens _who reside in Poland_ legally required to present particular Polish papers to Polish authorities when encountered inside the country? If not, then it would seem strange that such a requirement would apply to Polish citizens who don't reside in Poland. And the law you quote does not appear to say otherwise.

Comment: Yes, they have to present their ID when stopped by the Police or similar authority for violation of law, as in any country :) Maybe I was a little too harsh about keeping up to (stupid) law

Comment: There was a proposal for punishment, a fine of 5000 PLN (~1700CAD) for Polish dual-citizens who use their second-country passport to identify themselves to Polish authorities. It was however, dropped during the legislative process. Right now, some general law regarding no identification or lack of proper travel document would apply.

Comment: @EdmundDantes: Which countries qualify as "any" for you? As a Danish national residing in Denmark, for example, I'm required to _tell_ the police my name, date of birth, and address if they ask me -- but not to present any physical ID (as if I would carry my passport around in my daily life; it is stored away safely at home).

Comment: @HenningMakholm - this was a shortcut. They have to provide their identification, not necessarily the document. However, if an officer has doubts about the information I provide, or if I am going to be fined, the document is generally a better option, than a 24h visit to the police station for the purpose of identification.

Comment: @EdmundDantes What is the *third* country in this scenario? I only see two: Canada and Poland.

Comment: @user1014 third country is a term of art in European Union law meaning "a country that is not a member state of the European Union."

Answer (score 4):

> Since her Canadian passport lists her city of birth, she could be refused entry if she doesn't carry a Polish passport.

No, no, just no. A Polish citizen can **not** be refused entry into their own country. Exiting, however, is a different story if it becomes clear she's a Polish national.

That said, since the Schengen Area (of which Poland is part) is a single country for border purposes, if **not** exiting Schengen in Poland a Canadian passport will do.

However, if you **do** exit Schengen in Poland and it becomes clear that your wife's Polish, she won't be allowed to exit without a Polish passport or ID card.

So in that case, my advice is to get a Polish ID card while in Poland - it is free of charge unlike a passport (though sadly I don't know how long it takes to issue it), and is a valid travel document in Europe, so she'd be allowed to exit any Schengen country (including Poland itself) using it.

Comment: It will not be issued in 5 days :(

Answer (score 2):

I have travelled to Poland through Germany and noone batted an eyelash even or asked anything. I was born there and my CAN passport clearly states my place of birth. :) I don't go directly however because I know that I will have issues as I do not own a PL passport.